# Gradle --continue option not working with TaskExecutionListener

Tags: gradle

In my gradle file, I have 3 tasks of type `Test` as:

```
/**
 * This is a test block called 'sampleA' to run testng tests.
 */
task sampleA(type: Test) {
    include "**/Helloworld4a*"
}

/**
 * This is a test block called 'sampleB' to run testng tests.
 */
task sampleB(type: Test) {

    include "**/Helloworld4b*"
}

/**
 * This is a test block called 'sampleC' to run testng tests. 
 * This block depends on sampleB block.
 */
task sampleC(type: Test, dependsOn: sampleB) {

    include "**/Helloworld4*"
    exclude "**/Helloworld4a*"
    exclude "**/Helloworld4b*"
}
```

Now I created a plugin where I add a TaskExecutionListener to it. In the TaskExecutionListener, I only create a file per task irrespective of whether task is executed successfully or not.

1. sampleA will have test failures
2. sampleB will have test failures
3. sampleC will NOT have failures

When I run `gradle sampleA sampleB sampleC` it runs only `sampleA`, which is expected (since task failed)
But when I use `--continue` option, the result is same. Without adding listener I see both `sampleA` and `sampleB` being run.

Here is my Listener class

```
class TestInfraTaskListener implements TaskExecutionListener {
    /**
     * Generate the test results for the EMTestNGTest types
     */
    public void afterExecute(Task task, TaskState state) {
        if(task instanceof Test) {
            /* If testng test type, then generate results. */
            def resultHandler = new TestResultsHandler(task, state)

            /* Generate individual result files */
            resultHandler.generateResultFiles()

            resultHandler.uploadToJira()
            state.rethrowFailure()
        }
    }
}
```

When I set `ignoreFailure = true`, all 3 tasks are run. What is that I'm doing wrong here. I want only `sampleA` and `sampleB` to be run with `--continue` option.

My Gradle version is 1.11 (I do not have authority to upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally got it working with below rules:

1. DO NOT set `ignoreFailures = true` in your `Test` Tasks
2. DO NOT call `state.rethrowFailure()` OR `throw new GradleException(...)` in any condition (Whether task succeeded or failed)